# Hiding button in rails (Agile Web Development with Rails book)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, button, controller, agile, hidden

This is my first question so I hope I can be as specific as possible, but don't be harsh.

I'm going through Agile Web Development with Rails and am very new to programming.

I want to hide a 'Checkout' button while I am on the order/new page so that it can't do anything nasty to the users purchase.

At the moment, I don't really understand how instance variables work, since it seems like no matter where I declare my instance variable, in a view or in orderscontroller#new, it always validates to true.

This seems to be the case because when I use the instance variable in the view to hide a div ( with hidden_div_if(condition == true) ) the buttons ALWAYS get hidden!

Not only that, but when I do:

```
<%= hidden_div_if( @hide_checkout_button == false ) do %>
<td><%= button_to 'Empty cart', cart, :method => :delete,
                  :confirm => 'Are you sure?' %></td>
<% end %>
<%= hidden_div_if( @hide_checkout_button == true ) do %>
  <td><%= button_to "Checkout", new_order_path, :method => :get %></td>
<% end %>
```

BOTH buttons get hidden! How can that be!?!

In this example, I have placed the variable declaration in views\orders_form.html.erb:

```
<%= @hide_checkout_button = true %>
<%= form_for(@order) do |f| %>
  <% if @order.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@order.errors.count, "error") %> 
        prohibited this order from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
        <% @order.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    ...
```

Here is a discussion-forum with solutions for this problem, but they don't work for me and I don't know why: http://pragprog.com/wikis/wiki/Pt-G-2/version/35

And here is the question itself:

> What happens if you click the Checkout button in the sidebar while the
>   checkout screen is already displayed? Can you find a way to disable
>   the button in this circumstance? (Hint: variables set in the controller
>   are available in layouts and partials as well as in the directly rendered
>   template.)

If you need any more information to help please ask, I'm not quite sure how much detail to provide or what information is important.

Thanks in advance :-)

```
def new
    @cart = current_cart
    if @cart.line_items.empty?
      redirect_to store_url, :notice => "Your cart is empty"
      return
    end

    puts 34
    @hide_checkout_button = true
    @order = Order.new
    puts 37

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @order }
    end
  end
```

> Started GET "/assets/logo.png" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-11-13 20:33:40 +0000
>   Served asset /logo.png - 304 Not Modified (1ms)
>   [2012-11-13 20:33:40] WARN  Could not determine content-length of response body.
>    Set content-length of the response or set Response#chunked = true
>   *
>   34
>   37
>   *
>   /orders/new
>
> Started GET "/orders/new" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-11-13 20:33:49 +0000
>   Processing by OrdersController#new as HTML
>     ←[1m←[36mCart Load (1.0ms)←[0m  ←[1mSELECT "carts".* FROM "carts" WHERE "carts
>   "."id" = ? LIMIT 1←[0m  [["id", 63]]
>     ←[1m←[35m (1.0ms)←[0m  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "line_items" WHERE "line_items"."c
>   art_id" = 63

Comment: Just a small bone to pick. Agile is a development methodology not a rails technology. It determines how you approach development problems, but doesnt have anything to do with why the code you provided would work or not work :).

Comment: Also the Hint is not a 100% accurate : `instance variables` are available, `local variables` are not

Comment: @gbt, its the title of the book (which is why it is capitalised) not my description - thanks for the comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is a missing `=`.  do `<%= %>` instead.

```
<%= hidden_div_if( @hide_checkout_button == true ) do %>
  <td><%= button_to "Checkout", new_order_path, :method => :get %></td>
<% end %>
```

Also, for boolean checks you can just do `if(boolean)` which will evaluate the same as if you put `==` `true`/`false`

```
<%= hidden_div_if( @hide_checkout_button) do %>
   #...
<% end %>
```

You want to set that variable on the method that calls the view.  In this case it is the `new` method in `OrdersController`

```
def new
  @hide_checkout_button = true
end
```

**Edit:**

add this to the hidden div just to see if it helps finding the element to set the attribute to

```
<%= hidden_div_if(@hide_checkout_button, id: 'cart') do %>
```

with (in the application helper)

```
def hidden_div_if(condition, attributes = {}, &block 
  if condition
    attributes["style"] = "display: none" 
  end
  content_tag("div", attributes, &block)
end
```

if that doesn't do it, then just do it this way

```
<% if @hide_checkout_button %>
  <td><%= button_to "Checkout", new_order_path, :method => :get %></td>
<% else %>
  <td><%= button_to 'Empty cart', cart, :method => :delete, :confirm => 'Are you sure?' %></td>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for responding,

That = made both of them appear all of the time. I recognise that was one mistake, but there is something else I am doing wrong.

I have the instance variable in orderscontroller#new and in the hidden_div_if method around the button. But the 'Checkout' button is still visible in the checkout page after I "get" new_order_path

Comment: `new_order_path` will hit the `new` method then the view.  To test you have the right value print it in the view before the div.  Show that method.

Comment: <td><%= print new_order_path%></td>

So this is what I put between the buttons and I got a blank space. It also says in the IDE [squiggly grey underline]"Cannot find new_order_path," but I stupidly ignored that because the Rubymine IDE says all kinds of things I don't understand and it hasn't stopped anything being saved to the orders or the application linking to the new#order page in my browser.

Any ideas? I can't understand how it can't find the new method in orderscontroller, if that is the problem...

Comment: http://localhost:3000/orders/new

This is the url in the browser that this button creates, and it links to the page effectively

Comment: Make sure you have `resources orders` in `config/routes.rb`.  You cant ignore that error message. It means its not finding the path.

Comment: But it is finding the path, it has the correct url in the browser: http://localhost:3000/orders/new I don't want to ignore it though, I just don't know what it means not to be able to find the path if the browser has the right url and the def new method is being called in orderscontroller. I'll check the route file though, thanks

Comment: Yip, resources :orders is there

Comment: Did you restart the web server after you updated routes.rb?  The method `new` will be called before the view so you can debug there if the path is being hit.

Comment: I didn't update routes.rb, resources :orders was already there, which I thought it would be because it goes in automatically with you create the orders model. But I'm restarting it anyway for the sake of trying anything

Comment: Thanks a lot, hidden_div_if never worked but an if else statement was fine in the end - with nearly the same amount of code. Was stupid to use that at the start.

Answer (score 0):

used

```
<div class="actions">
<% if not @hide_checkout_button %>
<%= button_to 'Checkout', new_order_path, method: :get, class: "checkout" %>
<% end %>
<%= button_to 'Empty cart', cart, method: :delete, data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" }, remote: true %>
```